# SSRS Chart showing list of employees with departments along the x-axis and a symbol / x for which ones they have access to

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

** UPDATE **
Found solution:

I added a dummy field called flag with a '1' in it to each row in my dataset.  When I tried using this field in the Matrix Wizard, it wasn't letting me, however when I dragged the Matrix down to the work space and added the fields I wanted manually, it allowed me to.  This gave me the simple output I was looking for.

---

original question:

having difficulty explaining in words what I'm trying to achieve which has made it difficult to search for but the image below should help I hope:

The output I'm looking for:

```
                   [ DEPARTMENT 1]   [DEPARTMENT 2]    [DEPARTMENT 3]   [DEPARTMENT 4]
                   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     [EMP JACK]           X                                  X
     [EMP TOM]            X                X   
     [EMP JOHN]           X                X                 X                  X
     [EMP AL]                                                                   X
```

My data looks like this

```
                  EMP_NAME    |     DEPTARTMENT_NAME
                  ------------------------------------
                  EMP_JACK    |     DEPARTMENT 1
                  EMP_JACK    |     DEPARTMENT 3
                  EMP_TOM     |     DEPARTMENT 1
                  EMP_TOM     |     DEPARTMENT 2
                  EMP_JOHN    |     DEPARTMENT 1
                  EMP_JOHN    |     DEPARTMENT 2
                  EMP_JOHN    |     DEPARTMENT 3
                  EMP_JOHN    |     DEPARTMENT 4
                  EMP_AL      |     DEPARTMENT 4
```

I'm just trying to show a list of the employees with what departments they have access to.  Probably is when I try to create a Matrix, I don't know what to put in for Values without getting an error.  Maybe a calculated field?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try putting in an expression `=IIF(Department_Name = "", 0, 1)`

Comment: @SS_DBA I found a solution which I've updated the original question with, thank you! your response actually helped me think outside the box and try it

Comment: I think you would need to check for NULL values, not empty - `=IIF(ISNOTHING(Department_Name), "", "X")`